# How to extract every word before '-' with php

Tags: php

How can I exrtact every word before `-`. What I mean is if I have

```
word - word word
or
word word2 - word word
or 
word word2 word3 - word word
```

I need every word before `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $line="word word2 word3 - word word";
  $words=explode(" ",trim(substr($line,0,strpos($line,"-"))));
  print_r($words);
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/TPahyXca)**

**One Liner**

```
print_r(explode(" ",trim(substr($line,0,strpos($line,"-")))));
```

Comment: Haha, I came up with literally the exact same solution; trim() and all  :)

Comment: The only difference was some spaces and I called your $line variable $test_string.  Not sure why I find that so amusing.  Maybe it's too late  :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :). It can even be made a one liner, would be a little more difficult to understand though

Comment: Thank's thas was realy... simple.